# graphRequest.start returns no data

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook SDK for login with iOS using Swift 3.

This my code. The problem is that no values are returned.

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var uLoginButton: UIButton!

let loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = {

    let button = FBSDKLoginButton()

    button.readPermissions = ["email"]

    return button;

}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(loginButton);
    loginButton.center = view.center
    loginButton.delegate = self

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil) {
        fetchProfile();
    }

    self.style()
}

func fetchProfile(){

    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "email, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"])

    let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()

    connection.add(graphRequest, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in

        if error != nil {

            //do something with error
            print("No Data returned")
            print(result)
        } else {

            //do something with result
            print("Data returned")
            print(result)

        }

    })

    connection.start()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func style(){
    self.email.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    self.password.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    self.uLoginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15;

}
```

}

extension ViewController : FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate{

```
internal func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

    // when the login is correct!
    print("Success login!");
    fetchProfile()
}

internal func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

internal func loginButtonWillLogin(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3, this is how you want to perform Graph Request.

1. Initialize FBSDKGraphRequest
2. Initialize FBSDKGraphRequestConnection
3. Add request to request connection
4. Start connection.

so,

```
let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "email"])
    let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
    connection.add(graphRequest, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in

        if error != nil {

            //do something with error

        } else {

            //do something with result

        }

    })

    connection.start()
```

Comment: Hi!
This run ok! but, i don't to get the data ( email, user_name, etc... )... i'm testing with "print(result)" but, no data returned

Comment: In that case there might not be a facebook user at the point you are calling graph request. Are you calling this before or after user has logged in?

Comment: the idea is to call the function when button has been clicked

Comment: Looks like it may be returning nothing because there is no field type "picture.type(large)". Try the graph request without it. List of available fields are listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user